# Pegar propriedade de um objeto com jquery e alterar o seu estilo com css

Tags: php, jquery, css

Problema: eu monto um Modal de notícia com propriedades de um objeto, porém, na propriedade title do objeto eu preciso passar o número de visualizações dinamicamente, e preciso alterar a fonte do número de visualizações. O que acontece é que quando o usuário passa o mouse em cima do title, o estilo que eu apliquei aparece, ou seja, aparece código HTML pro usuário final

**EXEMPLO**

```
config = {
            title: (data.nmcategoria || 'Geral') + ' | ' + data.dtpublicacao + ' | ' + data.nmtitulo + '<h6 style="line-height:7px;">' + data.nrvisualizacao + ' visualizações' + '</h6>', 
            content: tpl,
            isConfirm: false,
            titleElippsis: true,
            modalHeight: 568,
            modalWidth: 1024,
            justText: true
```

A ideia que tive pra solucionar isso, foi pegar a propriedade title do objeto, e mudar os estilos com jquery e css, algo tipo assim:

```
var pegaObj = $(config).attr('title', 'style',  'line-height:7px;');
```

porém sem sucesso, alguma dica galera?

Comment: deixa ver se entendi, você quer alterar o stylo quando a condição mudar correto? acredito que isso te ajudara: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: toda vez que o usuário abrir o modal, o número de visualizações aparece, até aí correto. Porém, como eu mudei o estilo no title, toda vez que o cursor vai em cima do title aparece código HTML pro usuário ver. Vou dar uma olhada naquela documentação

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o método `css()`da bilioteca jQuery para aplicar estilos ao elemento desejado.

Desta maneira:

`var pegaObj = $(config).css({"line-height":"1", "width":"250px"});`

Ou se preferir, pode criar uma `classe` específica, definir alguns estilos e aplicá-la com `addClass()` no elemento desejado.

Para mais informações você pode consultar a API do jQuery nos links abaixo:

Aplicar CSS com jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Aplicar uma classe ao elemento com jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Você pode também tentar o seguinte:

```
// Pega o elemento
var pegaObj = $(config);
// Aplicar o estilo ao elemento pego pelo jQuery 
pegaObj.css({"line-height":"1", "width":"250px"})
```

Comment: exatamente o que eu estava tentando fazer, porém eu preciso pegar a classe da div que o Modal está, por propriedade de objeto o Jquery não consegue aplicar os estilos, então to tentando resolver assim:

Comment: $("div[class='modal'] > h4").css({
    "line-height":"7"
   });